# ¿Cómo hacer despliegue de una aplicación ASP.NET Core en GNU/Linux con Apache?

Tags: c#, linux, apache, asp.net-core

buenos días, me gustaría contar con su ayuda para solucionar esta duda que tengo sobre realizar un despliegue de ASPnet 5 (Core1, CoreCLR) sobre un subdominio. cuento con lo siguiente:

1. Entorno: GNU/Linux Apache MySQL PHP.
2. DNV instalado (.net core y mono)
3. Generador Yeoman.

Al darle "dnx web", me funciona en http://localhost:5000
Esta app la tengo bajo una carpeta en un subdominio: http://subdominio.dominio.com/aspnet5/fx

¿Cómo le hago para que la app funcione en ese entorno de producción?
Me han recomendado hacer un docker container con nginx (+reverse proxy) y este fin de semana veré este tema.

Comment: El servidor en produccion lo controlas tu, o es un hosting de terceros? si tu lo controlas y cuenta con linux podrias simplemente ejecutar el dnx web y hostearlo en ese web server

Comment: Es un VPS que utilizo como laboratorio de aprendizaje, cuenta con GNU/Linux. Ya ejecute el dnx web dentro de la ruta mencionada y no puedo visualizarla. Siento que hay algo que me falta

Comment: Validaste que el subdominio.dominio.com este bien mapeado en ip y puerto en el router ? porque es el route quien redirecciona de la ip de WAN a la ip y purto de LAN para resolver contra el servidor local

Comment: así es, tengo otras apps funcionando bajo ese subdominio, en diferentes carpetas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es configurar Apache como Reverse Proxy de forma que las peticiones realizadas al directorio `aspnet5/fx` se redirijan a tu aplicación ASP.NET Core

```
http://subdominio.dominio.com/aspnet5/fx --> http://localhost:5000/aspnet5/fx
```

Los pasos para realizar esta configuración son los siguientes:

1. Instalar y habilitar los módulos de Apache para Reverse Proxy

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-proxy-html libxml2-dev
   sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_ajp proxy_http rewrite deflate headers proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_html
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
2. Modificar la configuración de tu sitio web de Apache para añadir la redirección (suele ser el archivo `000-default.conf` ubicado en `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`)

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:*>
      ...

      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass /aspnet5/fx/ http://localhost:5000/aspnet5/fx/
      ProxyPassReverse /aspnet5/fx/ http://localhost:5000/aspnet5/fx/
      ServerName localhost
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Configurar la url `http://localhost:5000/aspnet5/fx/` en la aplicación ASP.NET Core. Esto se hace añadiendo en el archivo `hosting.json` ubicado en la raíz del proyecto

   ```
   {
       "server.urls": "http://localhost:5000/aspnet5/fx/"
   }
   ```

> Este último paso es necesario para que se resuelvan las rutas que
>   hacen referencia a la raíz de la aplicación, es decir, las que
>   comienzan por `~/` pero en la versión RC1 **no está funcionando**

Lo que te recomiendo es que te crees otro subdominio `aspnet5-fx.subdominio.dominio.com` que sea el que proporciona acceso directo a tu aplicación ASP.NET Core.

En este caso lo que tendrías que hacer es:

1. Crear un archivo de configuración de Apache para tu nuevo dominio (podrías hacerlo ejecutando el comando `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/001-aspnet.conf`)
2. El contenido de este archivo sería la siguiente

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:*>
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
      ServerName aspnet5-fx.subdominio.dominio.com
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Por último tienes que habilitar el nuevo sitio web y recargar la configuración de apache

   ```
   sudo a2ensite 001-aspnet
   sudo service apache2 reload
   ```

Algo que también es importante es que los archivos de tus aplicaciones **ASP.NET Core** no deberían estar ubicados dentro del directorio de contenido de **Apache**, es decir en `/var/www/aspnet5/fx`, porque al hacer de `reverse proxy` no es necesario y si algo falla en la configuración, podrían llegar a acceder a los archivos de código. Lo recomendado sería ser ubicarnos, por ejemplo, en `/opt/aspnet5/fx`

Comment: Perfecto! gracias! Por curiosidad, a que te refieres con la parte final? "Por cierto, no es necesario ni recomendable que los archivos de tu aplicación ASP.NET Core estén bajo el directorio de contenido de apache"

Comment: @fredyfx He modificado el último párrafo para que se entienda mejor. Espero que aclare tus dudas

Comment: excelente! ahora si quedo claro, gracias nuevamente @rsciriano!

Answer (score 5):

Primero quiero aclarar que para "empaquetar" la aplicación, previo al despliegue, se debe usar el comando [`dnu publish`](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-Utility#publish-dnu-publish), para ver la lista de opciones puedes usar: `dnu publish --help`.

Luego de empaquetar, en la carpeta donde se haya puesto el resultado del empaquetado (puedes usar la opción `-o` para especificarlo) habrá una carpeta `approot` con una utilidad `web`, esta será la que se llame [desde el servidor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31479524/1229323).

Cabe aclarar que sí es posible exponer la aplicación sin necesidad de un reverse proxy. [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) inicia en el puerto 500x y cambiarlo al puerto 80 [obligaría a usar root](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/311#issuecomment-73755715). Puedes, si lo deseas, usar el [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) para redirigir las peticiones al proceso de kestrel en el puerto 500x, pero esto bajaría, creo, el servidor que ya despacha sobre este puerto.

Además de lo mencionado, Kestrel [no es un servidor para producción](http://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/3-consejos-para-hacer-hosting-de-aplicaciones-ASPNET-5-%28vNext%29-con-Kestrel.aspx) y, como anotas en la formulación de la pregunta, lo recomendable es usar algo como Apache o nginx. Dices que en el momento cuentas con Apache, [creería que es posible](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension) usarlo para tal fin pero no lo he visto, yo actualmente uso nginx (sin Docker, aún no lo he necesitado) para esto.